# Node js issue with loop order

Tags: node.js

Hello i really need help with this issue, my last console.log is execute BEFORE the for loop and i dont know how to fix it. I really need to have access at my array nbfilm after the for loop

Can someone help me?

What the console print : [lien](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSicb.png)

```
client.db.query("SELECT name,id FROM film", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

          const catalog = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Catalogue")
            .setColor("#fcfe80")
            .setFooter({text:" ・ PopFlix"})

            let testresult =[]
            let nbfilm =[]
            for (let compteur of result){
                testresult.push(compteur.id)
                testresult.push(compteur.name)
            }
            console.log(testresult)
            for (let compteur2 = 0; compteur2 < testresult.length; compteur2+=2){
                client.db.query(`SELECT link FROM lien WHERE fid=${testresult[compteur2]}`, function (err,result) {
                    
                    nbfilm.push(testresult[compteur2+1])
                    nbfilm.push(result.length)

                    console.log("nbfilm in for loop",nbfilm)

                });
                

            }

            console.log("nbfilmAFTER",nbfilm)
});
```

Comment: which package are you using for "client.db.query"?

Answer (score 0):

The body of the loop delays execution. Due to the fact that javascript is an asynchronous i/o type operation language, it is common to return a promise. In other words, the code is executed as expected, but the result of the actions will be visible only after all pending tasks have been completed. In your case, adding async/await in code might help. Use it [node docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Comment: I've already read lot of docs like this but i really don't know how to adapt this in my code :(

Answer (score 0):

`client.db.query()` is an asynchronous function and won't execute until after the `console.log(nbfilm)` is executed regardless of how fast that query actually runs.

I'd recommend using `Promise.all()`. You will also have to "promisify" the `query()` function. Pass everything you want to `resolve()`, and then concatenate them in the final line as below.

```js
let promises = [];

for(....) {
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   client.db.query("select ... ", () => {
       // all the same stuffs
       resolve([testresult[compteru2+1], result.length]);
   });
  }))
}

Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => results.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), []))
      .then(data => console.log(data));  // do whatever you want with "data"
```

Here's a simplified demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-all-example-78r347

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to help and return this : [link](https://i.imgur.com/DiPvYlj.png) 

But how can i stock the result in a variable please instead of log it with the console.log ?

Comment: I changed the last line of the sample code. You can do whatever you want with the "data"

Comment: I've some issues for accessing at the date after the promises, I dont know if i've done something wrong, code + console : [link](https://i.imgur.com/WbbEtBI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like client.db.query is asynchroneous. JS here works as expected because it doesnt wait for the query to be finished before moving to the next line.

Its now a better practice to use async/await instead of callbacks. If you provide the package that you are using we can provide a code example.